# diff -y weird output

Tags: linux, diff

I have two files as follows:
file1.txt

```
0000075d-7f2c-4896-83b4-5738d23bc4ba
000066c6-1184-47fc-acf6-916cb640c3f4
0000913e-adf2-41be-b377-749bd656cbf5
0000cb55-9b2c-42ea-af3e-87d2c7713c13
00012ac0-a893-41c7-a806-27728a1127e2
00013bea-4be2-4270-8efe-c00cd57b525d
00014c1d-6a5d-4c5e-aff0-a44cf49c54d5
0001d18b-c5c8-41c4-bcb0-e3c8074cb39e
00022848-b122-4c6a-b810-51737db09a5b
00022b1e-0148-4dad-bb82-a9be457ed2e7
```

file2.txt

```
0000075d-7f2c-4896-83b4-5738d23bc4ba
0000116d-4255-427c-9319-a60170770d40
000032d2-3795-4b38-a222-b6599061b467
00004090-fbf1-4fd5-80cc-1f34d45af7a1
0000456e-1070-46c0-83e4-6fff495b89a3
00005b49-5266-405e-b4d3-d9a441bc38e3
000066c6-1184-47fc-acf6-916cb640c3f4
000099a6-d457-47fb-a274-63eb566bfd44
00012ac0-a893-41c7-a806-27728a1127e2
00013bea-4be2-4270-8efe-c00cd57b525d
```

When I run

```
diff -y file1.txt file2.txt
```

I got following weird output:

```
0000075d-7f2c-4896-83b4-5738d23bc4ba                            0000075d-7f2c-4896-83b4-5738d23bc4ba
                                                              > 0000116d-4255-427c-9319-a60170770d40
                                                              > 000032d2-3795-4b38-a222-b6599061b467
                                                              > 00004090-fbf1-4fd5-80cc-1f34d45af7a1
                                                              > 0000456e-1070-46c0-83e4-6fff495b89a3
                                                              > 00005b49-5266-405e-b4d3-d9a441bc38e3
000066c6-1184-47fc-acf6-916cb640c3f4                            000066c6-1184-47fc-acf6-916cb640c3f4
0000913e-adf2-41be-b377-749bd656cbf5                          | 000099a6-d457-47fb-a274-63eb566bfd44
0000cb55-9b2c-42ea-af3e-87d2c7713c13                          <
00012ac0-a893-41c7-a806-27728a1127e2                            00012ac0-a893-41c7-a806-27728a1127e2
00013bea-4be2-4270-8efe-c00cd57b525d                            00013bea-4be2-4270-8efe-c00cd57b525d
00014c1d-6a5d-4c5e-aff0-a44cf49c54d5                          <
0001d18b-c5c8-41c4-bcb0-e3c8074cb39e                          <
00022848-b122-4c6a-b810-51737db09a5b                          <
00022b1e-0148-4dad-bb82-a9be457ed2e7                          <
```

This output looks strange as:

```
0000913e-adf2-41be-b377-749bd656cbf5                          | 000099a6-d457-47fb-a274-63eb566bfd44
```

I am not sure what this output means here, as they are different, but they are in same line, with "|" in the middle.

Please let me know if anyone knows why.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [documentation for GNU diffutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Side-by-Side), which provides descriptions of the markers used in side-by-side and the following example output:

```
The Way that can be told of is n   <
The name that can be named is no   <
The Nameless is the origin of He        The Nameless is the origin of He
The Named is the mother of all t   |    The named is the mother of all t
                                   >
Therefore let there always be no        Therefore let there always be no
  so we may see their subtlety,           so we may see their subtlety,
And let there always be being,          And let there always be being,
  so we may see their outcome.            so we may see their outcome.
The two are the same,                   The two are the same,
But after they are produced,            But after they are produced,
  they have different names.              they have different names.
                                   >    They both may be called deep and
                                   >    Deeper and more profound,
                                   >    The door of all subtleties!
```

The `|` marker basically indicates that the line exists in both files, but has been modified.

In your example, the diffing algorithm decided that the contents between the two files on that line were similiar enough that they represented the same line, with modifications.